# Binding to css transform scale using knockout

Tags: binding, knockout.js, transform

I am trying to scale a `<div>` with child elements by binding to a slider value using Knockout. Everything works except the actual transform:

```
<div id="scaleTest" data-bind="style:{msTransform: 'scale(' + scaleValue + ')'}">
  <div data-bind="text: scaleValue">
</div>
```

The text inside the `<div>` changes as the `ko.observable` `scaleValue` tracks the slider value, but the transform does not scale the `<div>`.

Just using:

```
data-bind="style:{msTransform: 'scale(' + 2 + ')'}"
```

works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any time you have a complex expression (anything more than a simple `binding: someValue`) that you are binding that uses observables, always remember to call the observable to obtain the value.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add brackets to `scaleValue`:

```
<div id="scaleTest" data-bind="style:{msTransform: 'scale(' + scaleValue() + ')'}">
```

Comment: @JohnVarney You should accept this answer as the correct one if it fixed your problem.